# Better way of identifying ranges of numbers in SQL Server other than a cursor

Tags: sql-server-2008, cursor

We have a SQL Server data base that holds service records.  Each service record has a service id.  The service ID is made up of the date, the client number, service rep, and then an incremental piece that goes up 1 every order for that day.  Also, our service techs can have more than one service record at any site, so there is also a Main Service ID assigned to the service ID as well.  The Main Service ID is first service ID for that site.  So the service ID and the main service ID can be the same if there is only one service being done at that site.  If there is more than one service being done, the service ID and main service ID would be different.

I’ve been tasked with seeing if there are any gaps in the service ids.  So, I created a query that identifies the lowest service ID for each Main Service ID.  I need a way to generate all the service ids between the service ID and main service ID for each section.  I’m using a cursor because I can’t think of another way to do this.  So my question is there has to be a better way to do what I am trying to do.  Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Here is my Cursor:

```
DECLARE @ServiceID as Varchar(12), 
        @ MainServiceID as Varchar(12),
        @TempSCR as Varchar(12)

DECLARE db_RecSet CURSOR FOR 
SELECT [ServiceID], Max([MainServiceID]) as MainServiceID
FROM Service_Table
WHERE MainServiceID like '12%'
AND [MainServiceID] <> [ServiceID]
GROUP BY [ServiceID]

OPEN db_RecSet
FETCH NEXT db_RecSet INTO @ServiceID, @ MainServiceID

WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
    BEGIN
        SET @TempSCR = @ServiceID
        WHILE @TempSCR <= @ MainServiceID
            BEGIN
            INSERT INTO [Temp_Identifiy_Possible_SCRHeader](ServiceID, MainServiceID)
                VALUES (@TempSCR, @ MainServiceID)
            SET @TempSCR = @TempSCR +1
            END 
        FETCH NEXT FROM db_RecSet INTO @ServiceID, @ MainServiceID
    END
CLOSE db_RecSet
DEALLOCATE db_RecSet
```

Comment: Perhaps a recursive CTE ..?

Comment: How do you define a gap in this scenario? Since the service ID is composed of multiple elements, which ones must be sequential? It would be very helpful if you show some sample data to clarify what a gap 'looks like' in your case. And there are already [many questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search-new?q=sql+find+gaps) on this site about finding gaps; have any of them been useful?

Comment: I haven't used a CTE before, so I will look into that.  Pondlife, I've looked into the gaps, but all I am finding is how to identify the gaps and how to create ranges of numbers that make up the gaps.  What I am looking to do is create a master list of what SHOULD be there, then bounce it against what is there and identify what is missing.  I will pull some sample data.  Thank you!